# 'IDataErrorInfo' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' - WPF

Tags: wpf, validation

I try use IDataErrorInfo in WPF app on validation data, but if I try implement interface IDataErrorInfo in my class, I get this error:

**'IDataErrorInfo' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'** I using namespace System.ComponentModel. Any advance.

code is here:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Friend : IDataErrorInfo
        {
            private string _id;

            public string ID
            {
                get { return _id; }

                set { _id = value; }
            }

            private string _lastError;

            public string Error
            {
                get { return _lastError; }
            }

            string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
            {
                get
                {
                    switch (propertyName)
                    {
                        case "ID": if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
                                _lastError = "Please insert a name!";
                            break;

                        default: _lastError = string.Empty;
                            break;

                    }
                    return _lastError;
                }
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a compiler error? On which line do you actually get this error? Except for the last } your code seems fine. I think the error is not in the code example itself. You might try to include more information. Namespaces for instance.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am so stupid, namespace of WPF app is called same as  interface IDataErrorInfo. I must go a sleep, I am so tired. Thnak you.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a namespace
You may be importing a wrong DLL

Try to use Ctrl + Space in IDataErrorInfo. It is a namespace.
Or it might be the same name with your namespace that it gets confused.
In your import statement, you can try to rename your imported namespace:
using Error = System.ComponentModel; (for example)

Try this explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx

Have a look at the Framework section
What is your OS? It said it does not support Windows 8, and stuff.
Maybe try to use another library, or change your OS, or wait until your OS supports it.

Thank you,